# When is Activity.onBackPressed called in Android? (in relation to other callback functions)

Tags: java, android

When is Activity.onBackPressed called in my Android application? I'm not looking for the obvious answer of when the user presses the back button. I wan't the answer in relation to other "callback" functions.

Is is possible to be called during the execution of another function within the Activity class?

What is the case if I have my Activity class implement some typical interfaces used for your typical game? For example GLSurfaceView.Rendered? I'm having the feeling onBackPressed is called during GlSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame but I'm not 100 % sure yet. Even if this isn't the case, I want to know how it works. (It seems difficult to find this kind of simple information anywhere.)

Finally, below is a code example for the layout of my Activity class. The question is, however, not limited to this particular setup.

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements Renderer {

    onCreate(...) {

        layout = new FrameLayout(this); 
        GLSurfaceHolder glsurface = new GLSurfaceHolder(this, this);
        glsurface.setRenderer(this);
        layout.addView(glsurface);
        setContentView(layout);
```

GLSurfaceHolder is just a simple dummy class that extends GLSurfaceView. It has the onTouchEvent overloaded and simple passes the data over to the MainActivity class. (The design philosophy in this very, very simple app is just to focus all the sensory and other data to one place and then "make things happen"..)

Comment: it is called when you press the Back button..

Comment: Ah, I just found that the Renderer is called from another thread! Well, I guess that answers this particular question.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html

Answer (score 0):

onbackpressed will be called when you pressed back button. Default behaviour will be destroying the activity. To avoid override the onbackkeypressed or onkeypressed.